# parceljs with dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, bundler, parceljs

I want to try parceljs for minifying and bundling.

I have installed the parcel-bundler with npm, and i tried creating a index.js, main.js and main.css for testing.

**main.css**

```
.main
{
    color: red;
}
```

**main.js**

```
import classes from './main.css';

export default () => {
    console.log(classes);
};
```

**index.js**

```
import main from './main';

main();
```

In my layout.cshtml file i have included the index.js file, but this is where im stuck.
I know that i can run parcel from powershell\cmd, and it says the server is running on port 1234. However, i want to use dotnet run.

When running dotnet run like i normally do i get "Unexpected token" from the index.js file. I guess parcel does not run when starting dotnet run.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem. If you just want to run Parcel without the server you can do `parcel watch index.js` but you'll have to have this running at the same time as `dotnet` to get Hot Module Reloading. What we really need is the Parcel equivalent of `WebpackDevMiddleware`.

Another option is to use something like [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both commands at the same time. You could then setup an NPM script like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"dotnet run\" \"parcel watch index.js\""
}
```

and run:

```
npm run dev
```